# How get negated value inside spring boot application.yml

Tags: spring-boot, yaml

Is there any way to assign a negated value from a variable to another variable, configuring the application.yml spring boot file.
Something like

```
org:
 property: true
property2: !${org.property}
```

I tried few ways and always spring complains about it.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Negate it in your config class:

```java
@ConfigurationProperties("org")
public class AppProperties {
    private boolean property;

    // getter setter
}
```

```java
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(value = AppProperties.class)
public class AppConfig {
    private final AppProperties appProperties;
    private boolean property2;

    public AppConfig(AppProperties appProperties) {
        this.appProperties = appProperties;
        property2 = !appProperties.getProperty();
    }

    // getter setter
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you cant do any logic directly in YAML as YAML is just a text formatting language comparable to XML or JSON.